# sudo -s -H and aliases

Tags: bash, sudo, alias

I often use `sudo -s -H`, but want to have aliases after executing it
How to?

Explanation:
I log in server as user1 (which is in sudoers). This user has aliases in `.bash_aliases`:

```
alias rm='rm -i'
```

now I execute `sudo -s -H`

And now `rm` isn't aliased - so it removes files without prompt.

How to change it?

(i see posts with `alias sudo='sudo '` - but it works only executing command `sudo command` - not with `sudo -s -H`

Answer (score 1):

You have to source the same aliases under `/root/.bashrc`.

You can do this in 2 ways:

1. Copy `/home/user1/.bash_aliases` to `/root/.bash_aliases` and add the following to `/root/.bashrc`:

   ```
   if [[ -f /root/.bash_aliases ]]
   then
     . /root/.bash_aliases
   fi
   ```
2. Source the `/home/user1/.bash_aliases` file from `/root/.bashrc`:

   ```
    if [[ -f /home/user1/.bash_aliases ]]
    then
      . /home/user1/.bash_aliases
    fi
   ```

The solution you choose depends on personal preference. I'm using option 2, because I want root to have the same aliases etc. as my normal user, and in this way I only have to maintain it in 1 place (you could also make a symlink to `/home/user1/.bash_aliases` in `/root`, but the effect would be the same).

If you choose option 1, you have to maintain your aliases for both `user1` and `root` separately. This may or may not suit your use-case.